# Phaser stopwatch

Tags: phaser-framework

I have started a game and I want a stopwatch (countup timer) in it I have found a code to activate it. But how to stop it?
Source: https://docs.idew.org/video-game/project-references/phaser-coding/timers#create-count-up-timer

Code related to the stopwatch:

```js
//global vars 
var timeText; var min, sec;

function create timeText = game.add.text(600, 20, "", { fontSize: '20px', fill: '#FFF' }); timeText.fixedToCamera = true;

function displayTimeElapsed(){ 
    if (knight.x >= 96){ 
        var time = Math.floor(game.time.totalElapsedSeconds() ); 
        min = Math.floor(time / 60); 
        sec = time % 60; 
        if (min < 10) { 
            min = "0" + min; 
        }   
 
        if (sec < 10) {
            sec = "0" + sec; 
        } 
        timeText.text = "Time: " + min + ":" + sec; 
   } 
} 
//update displayTimeElapsed();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a `boolean pause` that if `true` it will set the time to what the remaining time is and when `false` keep doing what is doing.

it would be easier to explain it if you show your code. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets create it from scratch, 
first of all in your `create()` function, lets add a text to display the timer on the screen:

```js
// CREATE()
this.timerText = this.add.text(x, y, "").setColor("#000000");
```

Second lets create a function, bellow the `update()`, to count down :

```js
showTimer(){
    // Assuming you want 60 seconds, if not just chenge the 60's for whatever time you want 
    let maxTime = 60;
    let time = Math.floor(this.time.totalElapsedSeconds() );

    let sec = time % 60;

    timeText.setText(sec); // Adding the timer to our text
}
```

Third, create a variable in the `create()` to track when the timer ends:

```js
// CREATE()
this.timerOver = false; 

// And lets start the timer
this.timer = this.time.delayedCall(60000);
```

Now lets modify our `showTimer()` function:

```js
showTimer(){
    let maxTime = 60;
    let time = Math.floor(this.time.totalElapsedSeconds() );
    let timeLeft = maxTime - time; // Check how much time is left

    // When the countdown is over
    if(timeLeft <= 0){
        timeLeft = 0;
        this.timerOver = true; // Setting our variable to true
    }

    let sec = time % 60;

    timeText.setText(sec);
}
```

and last, in our `update()` function lets check if our variable `this.timerOver` is true

```js
if (this.timerOver === false){
    this.showTimer(); // Calling our function every frame
}
else {
    // Whatever you want it to do when timer comes to 0
}
```